# Google Maps API limitations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project where I am going to create a map over a specific area, and have some points-of-interest included. Thinking of the ones already included in Google Maps.

My first thought was that this could be done in the Google Maps API, but I've never worked with if before so therefor I have some questions about it's limitations and capability.

1. Can I limit the map to one specific area?
2. Can I filter the points-of-interest? Ex. only gas stations and hotels etc.

Thats about it to get me started at least.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: I am reading trough the documentation now. Was just wondering if anyone may have done the same thing and could verify that it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a spatial enabled db([postgis](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/),[mysql spatial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analysing-spatial-information.html)..) you can make spatial queries to filter your POI's.As of filtering according to type you should add a type column in your table to filter the results according to this column.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the extents fo the displayed map by intercepting the pan controls (eg. intercepting the view-change messages; or implement your own and disable the standard ones). Note that if you zoomed out a lot, the out-of-area-map would still appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can restrict your geocoder search by specifying the bounds [as described here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest)
2. AFAIK, no, unless you filter the results once you've obtained them